# Filtering ADOTable error - "could not convert type Null to type OleStr"

Tags: delphi, tadotable

I am trying to filter an ADOTable for records with a field 'OwnerName' value matches the one in a edit on my GUI component. When entering a name that does not exist, i get the above mentioned error. When there are no names in the database that match the filter, I just want the dbgrid to display nothing, how can this be done? Still a noob, so could anyone enlighten me?

***Code used:***

```
procedure TOwners.edt_Name_FilterChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Filter;
end;
//-----------------------------------------------------------
procedure TOwners.Filter;
begin
  if edt_Name_Filter.text = '' then
  begin
    CarOwners.tbl_Owners.Filtered := false;
    exit;
  end;

  with CarOwners do
  begin
    tbl_Owners.Filtered := false;
    tbl_Owners.Filter := 'OwnerName LIKE ''' + '%' + edt_Name_Filter.text +
      '%' + '''';
  if tbl_owners['OwnerName'] = null then
  begin
    tbl_owners.filter := '';
  end;
    tbl_Owners.Filtered := true;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `if tbl_owners['OwnerName'] = null`?

Comment: I tried to test if it is null, but i still get the exception error and the if does not excecute. I need help on how to implement this code correctly.

Comment: Try if VarToStr(tbl_owners['OwnerName']) = '' then or VarIsNull(tbl_owners['OwnerName'])

Comment: But *why* do you want to test if the field of the current record is null?

Comment: @Olivier, i get could not covert type Null into type OleStr at `tbl_Owners.Filtered := true;` when I enter an name or `edt_Name_Filter.text` value of 'ss'.

Comment: Testing the `OwnerName` field for null is useless since the `Filter` expression being used pretty much ensures that field can never be null.

Comment: @Remy, then why do I get the `cannot convert type(Null) into type(OleStr)` at `tbl_Owners.Filtered := true`?

Comment: The answer's in the data. Is the edt_Name_Filter.text <> '' when the code runs? What values are in the OwnerName column of the data? There might be an unexpected value in there, like a single quote or something like that. I'm guessing, but it's an educated guess based on my past experience.

Comment: @nolaspeaker, yes `edt_Name_Filter.text <> ''` when the code runs, if it does then the first if will handle it. The entire OwnerName column of data just consists of simple names Like: 'Joe','Sannie' ect...
To be more clear, this data is read form an ADOTable from a Datamodule from a .mdb file. I can check the .mdb file in microsoft access, there are no `Null` values.